# Simplify topology

Tags: topology, retopology, remesh

Can everybody tell me how to simplify topology of my model only with standard modifiers (without paid add-ons as Quadremesher or Jremesher)?

[image]

Link with my model:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fTsBXHDBQWi9WimTtvVgovRPfuMES29x/view?usp=drivesdk
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Andrii, welcome... please give folks a chance to assess your problem _before_ committing to a download, by illustrating. (Done for you, here).

Comment: Pardon. Thanks.

Comment: That's fine, no apology needed.. in general, catering for laziness will help you to attract answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is probably to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, then choose 2 or 4 in the *Operator Box*. You'll still need to bring some corrections to some parts of the topology:

[image]

You can also do it manually:

- Switch to *Edge Select* mode, select an edge ring with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> right click, then *Select > Checker Deselect* in order to unselect one edge out of 2 (or less):

[image]

- Then *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops* to extend the selections:

[image]

- And at last <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve the edges, here is the result (next, do the same for the horizontal edges):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How about Limited Dissolve, Remesher and Decimate? Is it possible to retopology my model with those add-ons?

Comment: Decimate > Un-Subdivide is actually the same as Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide. As for the other options I doubt they will give anything correct for this topology

Comment: Thanks. What about paid add-ons? which add-on is best for editing this kind of topology?

Comment: You have a free app like Instant Remesh or a paid app like Quad Remesher, see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CviZw41IbMg but for a manufactured, non-organical object, I'm not sure that it will be better than a simple Un-Subdivide operation (maybe Quad Remesher can do it, I've never tried it)

Comment: You can also do it with the Checker Deselect function, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I remeshed my model by your recommendations. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome, please don't use the Your Answer field to comment, it is made for answers   ;)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know, it's my firs experience on this public)